# Open fancybox on third page

Tags: jquery, popup, fancybox, fancybox-3

Hi I use opening fancybox for new visitors after 5s. I would like open popup not after time, but after open third (for example) page, which he visit. How can I make it?

My solution with timeout looks like that:

```
setTimeout(function () {
  $.fancybox({
    autoSize: false,
    height: 'auto',
    minHeight: 300,
    width: '50%',
    href: '/index/some-page',
    type: 'iframe',
    afterLoad: function (current) {
      current.content.contents().find('.not-interest').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        Cookies.set('not-interest', true, {expires: 14});
        $.fancybox.close();
      });
      current.content.contents().find('.some-form').submit(function () {
        var today = new Date();
        var date = new Date('Jan 1, 2038');
        var oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
        var diffDays = Math.abs((date.getTime() - today.getTime()) / oneDay);
        Cookies.set('interest', true, {expires: diffDays});
      });
    },
    beforeClose: function () {
      Cookies.set('close', true, {expires: 14});
    }
  });
}, 5000);
```

My idea is, count visit pages of user and save it to cookies. It is good way?

Comment: Yes, it it a good way.

Comment: Ok, I thought if is not some better solution:)